# Default operators with FA2 library in SmartPy

Tags: smartpy, fa2

I was wondering if, when using the FA2 library, there is a way to have the contract as a default operator so that users don't have to call update_operators ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by creating a new transfer policy.

Warning ⚠️ : having the contract be operator by default **may introduce a security flaw** or be totally fair depending on your contract's logic.

Here how to define a new policy:

```
import smartpy as sp
FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py")


# Inherits from the OwnerOrOperatorTransfer policy
# but you can choose another base policy.
class MyPolicy(FA2.OwnerOrOperatorTransfer):
    # Explicitely change the policy name.
    # This whole method can be remove if you want to keep the base policy name.
    def init_policy(self, contract):
        FA2.OwnerOrOperatorTransfer.init_policy(self, contract)
        self.name = "this-contract-or-owner-or-operator-transfer"

    # Redefine the transaction transfer's permissions.
    def check_tx_transfer_permissions(self, contract, from_, to_, token_id):
        sp.verify(
            (sp.sender == sp.self_address)
            | (sp.sender == from_)
            | contract.data.operators.contains(
                sp.record(owner=from_, operator=sp.sender, token_id=token_id)
            ),
            message="FA2_NOT_OPERATOR",
        )

    def is_operator(self, contract, operator_permission):
        # Add self_address to is_operator (used in offchain view)
        return (sp.sender == sp.self_address)
               | contract.data.operators.contains(operator_permission)
```

Here how you set the policy as a named argument when instanciating your FA2.

`c1 = FA2.Fa2<BaseClass>(..., policy=MyPolicy()).`

Here is [an example](https://smartpy.io/ide?code=eJzdVMtu2zAQvPsrCPUiobLs5BiAQNOgvjUuAt@CgKCpVUxEJAWSTmy0_fcuJUqyEjfNuQJsieRwH7M7K1VjrCdOceubI@GOuGa2ur4kFD8KaQrZApgTVjaeVdYotrd1muy8b9zVYhFvInThQTU19@AWFb9ktdwWzTHJZrOZqLlzZLOT7sZob7nwa7t@0WDx1YDl3tiN5dpVYFP0XfzlLLuaEXxKqIjU0rPG1FIcUwd1lRMRLUdQeN4xVbxjYLgf9gvNFSAZicfo5z1mbuzcBMvtR7Q999F4MhviFDsQT8wfWH_GEKykc9Jo98pxTlp2c@JN@_cEmsnyJB8syDNYWR3TYSs8Ke470CVYQtuqBbOMl6UF57IJ9NcrcOvwNaSPpyi550WfnSvCPpcY9gQfA7MgjC3TlhQa8@iv0sHnmBYd8ptYy_LJUmEG_BFogqVkt@sNW__4dne9Wd8lIy4b2ZaO9T7fcNsfnBTghFoLfm_1P6j8CDfn3KACvqAtNMNQHD4NLUWT29WGvEi_I7xUUhOuS4Jvj4IJqbTAGCDHLoVOkGGbcSHMXvs0uQ4HScfg1mzPQb6abQSIHbe1PGvnpjuKwK4yqkRkUJDiT8AUeB5SjrF_P5JNQCU58i6k4rWjFzlxR7U1NU3wLIllceLEoROguZUmjRFdRBcrfrna60e5rWFsrt5ld3_vZe2Kfo@ZajqF4MBx9gDWQSUnPdQJHC18bPac3IwkRH_0viflYYTUUD5is_9M2_oUsUtyssyuyMVyyZbL5e9Z16GRic8Uc@54@dSGNPQTtu7QoaTCH6DSj0ZDEZkq@gEyEnQ_kcqowTfybOVIp1G@AfmDo_ejEZxBFFtqzIqr0Cs0JnYi5GX2MJXwsOr2s8LuddqpimIiw2CKPMTmCwxo46cstA3@v1HQ5ZuTZwynpCvUDi7gIKDxOC3OzLrsD@eWV2A-).

Comment: In which cases could it be a security flaw ? Is it alright as long as I make good use of sp.verify ?

Comment: By itself it's not a security flaw. I simply recommend to check multiple time that your whole contract logic is ok with a by default operator.